# Bootstrap menu bar overlapping logo on collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When navbar collapse (when it shows the toggle icon), the menu (home, services, portfolio, about,contact) is over the logo. If I take the position:absolute from the logo (nag-bar-brand) the menu appears in the center.  If there away to have the menu below the logo. I hope you understand my question. English is not my first language. Thank you.
HTML

```
<!--navbar-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<div class="container">  

<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">

<span class="icon-bar"></span>`enter code here`    
<span class="icon-bar"></span>    
<span class="icon-bar"></span>

</button>

<a  href="#"class="navbar-brand"><img id="brand-image" src=""><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"  alt="website logo"></a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> 

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Service</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                                    
</ul>

</div>

</div>        
</div><!--end navbar-->
```

css:

```
.navbar {
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius: 0 px;
min-height: 85px;   
}

.navbar-nav{
padding-top: 20px;
letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
padding-left:20px;
}

.navbar .nav >li > a:hover{
color: #19bcb9;
}
.navbar-brand{
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is too big this will happen. Limit the image with max-height max-width

Comment: I fixed the problem (without modifying the logo size) by adding another div class "navbar-header", that contain the button and the logo.

Answer (score 0):

simply put the image size to 100%. this should work!

```
.img {
img-size:100%;
}
```